# Typescript narrowing to identical types narrows to never

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

I've run into this typescript error

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

I've produced a simplified example here ([code sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-dew-zfxrg?file=/src/index.ts))

```
interface Get {
  id: number;
}
interface Delete {
  id: number;
}

const isGet = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string): narrowMe is Get =>
  narrowBy === "GET";
const isDel = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string): narrowMe is Delete =>
  narrowBy === "DELETE";

const foo = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string) => {
  if (isGet(narrowMe, narrowBy)) {
    return narrowMe.id;
  }
  if (isDel(narrowMe, narrowBy)) {
    return narrowMe.id; // error happens here
  }
};
```

The real code is more complex, but essentially, the problem I think is that the two interfaces above are identical. If I add a fake field to `Get` interface, to make them different, then the error goes away. I'm struggling to find documentation on what exactly is happening here and how I can fix it or workaround it. Adding a fake field is hacky and I don't really want to combine `Get` and `Delete` into a shared type unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

`Get` and `Delete` interfaces are the same thing. TypeScript has something called duck typing, so after you check if `narrowMe` comforms to `Get` interface, TS knows it also comforms to `Delete` interface as well, so your second `if` is never actually possible. Things like that are usually solved with a discriminant:

```
interface Get {
  type: 'get';
  id: number;
}
interface Delete {
  type: 'delete';
  id: number;
}
```

I agree that it does look hacky, but that's just a nature of TypeScript type system. If two interfaces are the same, they describe the same set of possible objects. Their name just does not matter and you have to discriminate them somehow else.

```
interface Get {
  type: 'get';
  id: number;
}
interface Delete {
  type: 'delete';
  id: number;
}

const isGet = (narrowMe: Get | Delete): narrowMe is Get =>
  narrowMe.type === "get";
const isDel = (narrowMe: Get | Delete): narrowMe is Delete =>
  narrowMe.type === "delete";

const foo = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string) => {
  if (isGet(narrowMe)) {
    return narrowMe.id;
  } else if (isDel(narrowMe)) {
    return narrowMe.id; // no error, narrowMe is of type Delete
  }
};
```

Comment: I wonder if in my case, I should go about this differently, since I'm trying to narrow `narrowMe` by a different parameter`narrowBy`. This is what makes the second if possible. Even though `narrowMe` is the same, `narrowBy` can be different.

Comment: Well, sure, but `narrowBy` has to be connected with the interface. You will have to use discriminants, I'm afraid... See edit.

Comment: Why does `narrowBy` have to be connected with the interface? Is it not fair to narrow type A based on the value of type B?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that using type guards this way is not how they were intended, and thus will behave in unexpected manners.

The easiest solution is to base your logic on not on the type guards, but rather on the narrowBy variable:

```
interface Get {
    id: number;
}
interface Delete {
    id: number;
}

const isGet = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string): narrowMe is Get =>
    narrowBy === "GET";
const isDel = (narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string): narrowMe is Delete =>
    narrowBy === "DELETE";

function foo(narrowMe: Get | Delete, narrowBy: string): number {
    switch (narrowBy) {
        case "GET":
        case "DELETE":
            return narrowMe.id;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Invalid parameter narrowBy, expected "GET" or "DELETE" but got ${narrowBy}`);
    }

};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOITMg3gWAFDKHLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz4C++oksiKAIhADYYUuAkVIVq9Jq3z4EAexABnTMCXpMAXmQAKEHChR5AdwCyEChuQAfZH0GQANJQNHjAIQCeFFVFABzAEoJVxNzYiU0DGRNAD58IhdDEy8YzW0AIlQAUQAVDOY8BWVVJXsY3X1kswsozFt7IWcqty8fMD8QIJDq8LU7ASEY+NFCFpTPNMyebIAZPOyC2TwYKhAEMGBFZBh5eT1QmstohsGnJNbvZF8A4MpaBihsBKIlY2AwBAALSsOvQOeo0SyAQcCUKCyeQyZBewJBYIhM3muUWMKBcMIUAwVCgIAuYQgADpSIUMcgSBB4FR+GA0WTEmAvm5KBBjMhsskoDoAAYASRAADc4PxSMgAA4GOA0IRPcYeTzOCAADzFEA2EBIyEh+WQ8ieGSRCwyyDoVEw-nkmAAJFg5V4WNzAqSiGw8KxCvhdvssMRyMgAIzIFjObUZQJAA)